# Deploy an App into Azure App Service inside of Azure's Internal App Service Environment (ASE ILB)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-ilb, azure-ase

I have created a ILB in a VNET inside of Azure.

[image]

And I created an App Service Plan of that ASE (ILB) like below:

[image]

And I have hosted an App inside of the ILB. like below

[image]

To access the domain, I have created a Virtual machine inside of the VNET and added a host entry inside of that VM.

```
192.168.251.11 bb-pg-backend.bb-pg-ase2-app
```

So, when I hit the above URL (http://bb-pg-backend.bb-pg-ase2-app) I can see the below page.

[image]

Now from inside of the VM, I want to publish my code to the app service. I can create the profile successfully.

[image]

The error it is showing is

[image]

Should it not automatically do the bonding with Azure ASE (ILB) and publish the code to the app service?

Answer (score 1):

When I downloaded the publish profile from Azure, I found the below URLs.

> publishUrl="bb-pg-backend.scm.bb-pg-ase2-app:443"

[image]

So, I added a new host entry with scm word

```
192.168.251.11 bb-pg-backend.scm.bb-pg-ase2-app
```

Then I could successfully deploy from Visual Studio. An empty web api application with Values Controller would return data like below.

[image]

That's all. Thanks.